# KeyError: 'textAnnotations' while doing OCR using Google Cloud Vision API

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision, keyerror

I'm following [this](https://medium.com/google-cloud-platform-by-cloud-ace/cloud-vision-api-ocr-with-notebook-on-gcp-6b6d10f089cd) tutorial on OCR. I did everything the same as mentioned in the tutorial but I'm getting this error `KeyError: 'textAnnotations'` while generating the request in the last part. Could I know how do I fix this? My input image is just a character `a`.

Here's how I'm creating the request:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import base64
IMAGE="gs://<project-name>/<folder>/<file-name>.jpg"
vservice = build('vision', 'v1', developerKey=APIKEY)
request = vservice.images().annotate(body={
    'requests': [{
       'image': {
          'source': {
             'gcs_image_uri': IMAGE
          }
      },
      'features': [{
          'type': 'TEXT_DETECTION',
          'maxResults': 3,
        }]
     }],
  })
responses = request.execute(num_retries=3)
print(responses['responses'][0]['textAnnotations'][0]['description'])
```

Comment: Please add the response and the code, this error means he can't find 'textAnnotations' in the response.

Comment: @Inga890 I'm following the tutorial that I've linked. In the end, they are creating a request. Its result should be the text in the image but I'm getting the keyerror. I have added the request above in the question.

Comment: The key error is from the print. do you get the responses? can u attach it?

Comment: You need to check that it detected the letter in your image. Check the length of `responses['responses'][0]` or print that out as a whole piece and see what's inside.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the response, returned by the API in case there is an error, is different from `responses['responses'][0]['textAnnotations'][0]['description']`.
My opinion is that there is an error, hence your response do not have the shape you think it has. As suggested by Caleb, I would print out the full response and see what is inside first

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when your image doesn't contain text. So, in that case there will not be any textAnnotations array.
Response will be like that
Array ( [responses] => Array ([0] => Array ( )))
You can simply add a check if textAnnotations exists in response array then send description else any other response you want.